# Google Slide API how to replace text 'Click to Add Text'

Tags: google-slides, google-slides-api

After I use Google Slide API to create slides for me, I see text box with text saying 'Click to add Text' , 'Click to add title',
And same for 2 column sides, how can i set the text for the right 'Click to add Text', and same for the left.

How can I programmatically find out those text boxes and set the text I want?

Here is the code: I 1) create a slide and make it TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS layout 2) create a Shape and 3) Insert Text to the Shape. But when I view the slide in google drive, i see 'Click to Add Text'

```
        IList<Request> requests = new List<Request>();
        String slideId = "MyNewSlide_001";
        requests.Add(new Request()
        {
            CreateSlide = new CreateSlideRequest()
            {
                ObjectId = slideId,
                InsertionIndex = 1,
                SlideLayoutReference = new LayoutReference()
                {
                    PredefinedLayout = "TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS"
                }
            }
        });

        String textBoxId = "MyTextBox_01";
        Dimension pt350 = new Dimension()
        {
            Magnitude = 350.0,
            Unit = "PT",
        };
        requests.Add(new Request()
        {
            CreateShape = new CreateShapeRequest()
            {
                ObjectId = textBoxId,
                ShapeType = "TEXT_BOX",
                ElementProperties = new PageElementProperties()
                {
                    PageObjectId = slideId,
                    Size = new Size()
                    {
                        Height = pt350,
                        Width = pt350
                    },
                },
            }
        });

        requests.Add(new Request()
        {
            UpdateShapeProperties = new UpdateShapePropertiesRequest()
            {
                ObjectId = textBoxId,
                ShapeProperties = new ShapeProperties
                {
                    ShapeBackgroundFill = new ShapeBackgroundFill
                    {
                        SolidFill = new SolidFill
                        {
                            Color = new OpaqueColor
                            {
                                ThemeColor = "HYPERLINK"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                Fields = "shapeBackgroundFill.solidFill.color,outline"
            },
        });

        // Insert text into the box, using the object ID given to it.
        requests.Add(new Request()
        {
            InsertText = new InsertTextRequest()
            {
                ObjectId = textBoxId,
                InsertionIndex = 0,
                Text = "New Box Text Inserted"
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is your code so far to create the slides? What have you tried?

Comment: @n179911 Very useful code snippet! Can I ask where did you find the documentation to write it? I could not find any code sample for the G Slides Java API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those boxes with "Click to add text" text are placeholder Shapes that are automatically copied onto your slide from the layout. That text is only visible in the editor: they wont have any text in present mode, unless you insert text into them directly.

You can insert text into them just like any other shapes in the Slides API.

- Read the page or presentation with one of the GET APIs
  (presentations.get or presentations.pages.get)
- Find the object IDs
  of the placeholders you want to write in. You can identify which is
  which looking at the
  [pageElement.shape.placeholder](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages#Page.Placeholder)
  message on each page element on your slide. You want the one with `type` = `TITLE` for the title, and so on.
- Call batchUpdate with an insertText request to add the text, just like you're already doing in your code

Some of this is covered in the [Edit text in a specified shape](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/writing#edit_text_in_a_specified_shape) in the documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to give my TITLE placeholder in a custom Layout a unique ID, so I can avoid the get step prior to the batch update? 

Ideally I want to:
1. create new slide from a custom layoutId
2. set the Title text

all in the same batch update request, without making a get call after #1, searching for the objectId and then making a separate request to accomplish #2.

Comment: Yes -- see the `placeholderIdMappings` parameter on `CreateSlideRequest` in batchUpdate. There's some documentation for this specific usecase [here](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/create-slide#filling_in_placeholders).