# How do I create a text placeholder within a shape using Google slides api?

Tags: google-slides-api

I want to create a TEXT_BOX shape in Google Slides using the API. With the following code, I am able to create it.

```
         {
            createShape: {
                objectId: uuid.v4(),
                shapeType: 'TEXT_BOX',
                elementProperties: {
                    pageObjectId: slideId,
                    size: {
                        height: {
                            magnitude: BODY_HEIGHT,
                            unit: 'PT'
                        },
                        width: {
                            magnitude: HALF_BODY_WIDTH,
                            unit: 'PT'
                        }
                    },
                    transform: {
                        scaleX: 1,
                        scaleY: 1,
                        translateX: MARGIN_LEFT,
                        translateY: MARGIN_TOP + TITLE_HEIGHT + 2 * PADDING,
                        unit: 'PT'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Within this textbox, I want to set a placeholder text - "Click here to type text". This should be shown only in edit mode and not presentation mode. How can I do that?

Comment: This might answer your concern. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690634/google-slide-api-how-to-replace-text-click-to-add-text

Comment: https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes#placeholder